# Help with evaluating $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty exp(-iwx) g(x) dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I am given the $$S(w) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty exp(-iwx) g(x) dx~.$$ I am also given that $$ g(x) = 1 - \frac{|x|}{\alpha},~~~|x| \le \alpha,~~~~ \alpha \gt 0. $$show that

How can I show that

> $$ S(w) = \frac{\alpha}{\pi} \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{w\alpha}{2}\right)}{ \left( \frac{w\alpha}{2}\right)^2} $$

I started by splitting up the integral as

$$
\pi S(w) =\int_{-\alpha}^0 \exp(-iwx) \left(1+\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)dx +  \int_{0}^\alpha \exp(-iwx) \left(1-\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)dx \\
= \frac{i\alpha w -\exp(i\alpha w) + 1}{\alpha w^2} - \frac{i\alpha w +\exp(-i\alpha w) - 1}{\alpha w^2}\\ 
$$  which upon simplification reduces to

$$ \pi S(w) = \frac{2 - 2\cos(\alpha w)}{\alpha w^2}  =  \frac{4\sin^2\left(\frac{w\alpha}{2}\right)}{ \alpha w^2} = \frac{4 \alpha \sin^2\left(\frac{w\alpha}{2}\right)}{ (\alpha w)^2} $$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Arashium I don't understand what you mean

Comment: but why? don't we consider the fact that $|x| \leq \alpha$?

Comment: oops, You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. Your computation is correct. Observe that
$$
\frac{4}{(\alpha\,w)^2}=\frac{1}{\Bigl(\dfrac{\alpha\,w}{2}\Bigr)^2}
$$
and on the right had side you have $\pi\,S(w)$.

Comment: How I never saw that, I'll never know. Thanks.